# How to get info from DB(MYSQL) and store the value inside the json in JSP

Tags: mysql, json, jsp

I have my code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#messageReceiver").tokenInput([
                {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
                {id: 11, name: "Python"},
                {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
                {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
                {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
                {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
                {id: 29, name: "C#"},
                {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
                {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
                {id: 41, name: "C"},
                {id: 43, name: "C++"},
                {id: 47, name: "Java"}
            ]);
        });
     </script>
```

And i want to replace the content of the array to the names inside my database.
For example {name : "Ruby"} is replaced by {name: "A Name from DB"}
Im using Jsp btw and that script is a Autocomplete script

Answer (score 0):

You could send JSONArray to jsp, and simply place in you `tokenInput` method.

Servlet:

```
User user1=getUserFromDB(1);
User user2=getUserFromDB(2);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put(user1.getUserID, user1.getUserName);
json.put(user2.getUserID, user2.getUserName);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(json);
request.setAttribute("subjects", array);
request.getRequestDispatcher("myJSP.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

JSP:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var subjects='${subjects}';
    $("#messageReceiver").tokenInput(subjects);

});
```

Comment: Sir i need data coming from database :/
That's what i am trying to get

Comment: Yes, you can. I used hard coded values in servlet to illustrate. You would have to replace it with your db code. See updated code.